# ROS Answers SE migration: slam gmapping

Tags: slam, navigation, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I'm trying to build a map from a bag file.

```
rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping
[ WARN] [1298485439.195475816, 1297352013.562990207]: Message from [/play_1298485437842772645] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [laser]. Resolved locally to [/laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.
[ WARN] [1298485454.051371332, 1297352028.420031693]: MessageFilter [target=/odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

In rxbag I've checked the bag file and there is /pose instead of /odom. How to do the transforms? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9184/slam-gmapping/) by [szokei](https://answers.ros.org/users/178/szokei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2011-02-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So the first thing you should do when you see these errors is to [load up rxconsole](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole) and look at the debugs/warnings/errors being produced by this node.  Be sure to specifically change the [logger level](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rxconsole#Logger_Levels) for gmapping to DEBUG, as your error message says.

It looks like you're actually missing the transform with the target frame of /odom and NOT the /odom message topic.  If you look at the [gmapping package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping), you'll see it subscribes to /tf and /scan, not an odom topic.

To figure out what transforms are missing, you should use [tf's view_frames](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#view_frames) function by commanding `rosrun tf view_frames`  This will allow you to see your current transform tree and to make sure that you aren't missing any necessary links.  At mininum, you will need /odom to /base_link and /base_link to /laser.  If these three are connected to each other in the right way, everything should run fine.

What's the output of rxconsole and tf view_frames?  That will let everyone know what the problem actually is so that we can respond more specifically.

---

Originally posted by [Chad Rockey](https://answers.ros.org/users/29/chad-rockey/) with karma: 4541 on 2011-02-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5